# Django Expire token Authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working on expiring a django Token for this I am following this https://medium.com/@yerkebulan199/django-rest-framework-drf-token-authentication-with-expires-in-a05c1d2b7e05

and my accounts/authentication.py file is like

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed

from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings


# this return left time
def expires_in(token):
    time_elapsed = timezone.now() - token.created
    left_time = timedelta(seconds=settings.TOKEN_EXPIRED_AFTER_SECONDS) - time_elapsed
    return left_time


# token checker if token expired or not
def is_token_expired(token):
    return expires_in(token) < timedelta(seconds=0)


# if token is expired new token will be established
# If token is expired then it will be removed
# and new one with different key will be created
def token_expire_handler(token):
    is_expired = is_token_expired(token)
    if is_expired:
        token.delete()
        token = Token.objects.create(user=token.user)
    return is_expired, token


# ________________________________________________
# DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES
class ExpiringTokenAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):
    """
    If token is expired then it will be removed
    and new one with different key will be created
    """

    def authenticate_credentials(self, key):
        try:
            token = Token.objects.get(key=key)
        except Token.DoesNotExist:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("Invalid Token")

        if not token.user.is_active:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("User is not active")

        is_expired, token = token_expire_handler(token)
        if is_expired:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("The Token is expired")

        return (token.user, token)
```

and I have added in settings.py like this

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'accounts.authentication.ExpiringTokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}

TOKEN_EXPIRED_AFTER_SECONDS = 10
```

Still token is not renewing , I have checked this authentication class is not triggering .

Answer (score 0):

try it in side of **expires_in** function

```
time_elapsed = token.created - timezone.now()
```

cuz **time_elapsed** should be **positive**  to get left_time

Comment: No issue is this file is not even working , and token is working fine even its expire.

Comment: Authentication class Works fine but the bug is in expires_in function